# Font issue in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts

Inside react public folder, I have `style.css` and `index.html`. Inside style.css I have written

```
*{
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}
```

This means `Roboto` font is applied to all the components. I have imported `Roboto` font link from google in `index.html`.
Now in `App.js`, I have the following routes

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Now, for any component, when I give pathname as forward-slash `/` and pathname, such as `/profile`, then it works perfectly, the component gets rendered and `Roboto` font also work but, if I give pathname as forward-slash `/` and pathname, such as `/profile` and again after that, if I add user id or username param like `/profile/:username`, then `Roboto` font does not get affected rather, it displays default font but, if I again remove `:username` param from `/profile/:username` and make it `/profile` then `Roboto` font works again. So what's the issue here. Why font is not working in that component after adding `/` and any pathname or params in that route.

Comment: Just write `*{
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}` to App.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, move the css file to your `/src` directory(e.g. /src/css/styles.css), and in the file where everything gets wrapped inside of the router import the css file by:

`import "./css/styles.css"`

(assuming the js file is directory located in the `/src` directory without any nesting)